# Create 2 titles/headings for a table with Python-docx

Tags: python, dataframe, docx, python-docx

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
ABC                 
                                XYZ
        2010    2011    2012    3 YEARS 
ROW1    A       A       A       A       
ROW2    B       B       B       B       
ROW3    C       C       C       C       
ROW4    D       D       D       D       
ROW5    E       E       E       E
```

and what I would like to do is put this table into a word document (using the python-docx package) which will keep the table in exactly this format, such that titles `ABC` and `XYZ` are also in the word document in the same position as in the dataframe. I can generate the actual table itself but I'm not too sure how to include the titles with it too, so any help would be appreciated, thank you!